# Jquery removing data from database after div is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to make sort of an alert system, with an alert that pops up on a users screen, but I am having one major issue, I can't figure out how to remove that div completely, I know I need to remove it from the database, but that's what I'm having trouble doing, I can't seem to find a way to grab the ID of the div from the database to use to delete from the database.
Here was my attempt at it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $(".alert").draggable();    
    $(".alert").click(function()
    {           
        var test = $("#warning").val();
        alert(test);
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");

    }); 
}); 
</script>
<style>
#warning
{   
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:rgb(230, 30, 30);
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;    
}   
#notice
{   
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    background-color:rgb(230, 80, 30);
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;    
}   
#generic
{   
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    background-color:rgb(150, 150, 150);
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;    
}
.blue
{   
    font-weight:bold;   
}   
</style>
<?php
function display_alerts($user_id)
{   
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "asdfghjkl", "database");
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `alerts` WHERE `user` = '$user_id'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {       
    ?>          
        <div id="<?php echo $row["style"]; ?>" value = "<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="alert"><?php echo $row["message"]; ?></div>
        <?php       
    }       
}
display_alerts("10");
?>
```

Comment: why not just use a form in this case, fyi `.val()` are for form inputs. but if you really insist on making this work thru those divs, you could use an ajax

Comment: @Ghost
That's what I need some help with, I'm not very good with Ajax, and I'm not too great at JQuery. I did add the `<form action="#" method="post">`, however there was still no change in the outcome.

Comment: then just use a normal form. why complicate things? just loop the entries like you did and wrap them in a form tag. of course thats just the beginning, you'll have to process the form and use a delete statement. using just `<form action="#" method="post">` alone isn't going to delete those records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `$.ajax()` route, just call that PHP which will handle the process:

```
$(".alert").click(function(){           

    var id = $(this).attr('value'); // where the id resides on the markup
    $.ajax({
        url: 'delete_alert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {id : id},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.message);

        }
    });

    $(this).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Then in your PHP (delete_alert.php):

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $message = '';
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "asdfghjkl", "database");
    $id = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $query = $db->query("DELETE FROM alerts WHERE id = '$id' ");
    if($query->affected_rows > 0) {
        $message = 'delete successful';
    } else {
        $message = 'delete failed';
    }

    echo json_encode(array('message' => $message));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works great, I've never used Ajax in that way before, so I'm glad I can try something new.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id with `$(this).attr("id")`

Then you have to pass this id to a php page for removal. As Ghost suggested, you can use a form or an [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can handle removing it through PHP(thats the only Ajax I know, since I have been working on live chats.) let me just test some more of it out and I will accept your answer c:

Comment: Quick question, this is the way I am deleting the data, is through a XMLHTTPRequest, this is my code
`xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("http://localhost/LID/remove_moderator_alert.php?alert_id="+ alert_id +"", true);
  xhttp.send();`(it's in a new function) I'm getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'http://localhost/LID/remove_moderator_alert.php?alert_id=1' is not a valid HTTP method.` any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Check the Ghost's answer. That is the way it would use it too.